# Is there an effective way to map seasons such that order is preserved on a time series?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to order the seasons i.e. 1999: winter, spring, summer, autumn, winter, 2000, winter, spring, etc

what I have at the moment is just long and not nice:

```
import calendar

df['month_num'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).month
df['year_num'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).year
df['year_month_num'] = df.month_num + (df.year_num +- 1999)*12

year_month_num_to_season_num =  {1:1,2:1,3:2,4:2,5:2,6:3,7:3,8:3,9:4,10:4,11:4,12:5,
                                 13:5,14:5,15:6,16:6,17:6,18:7,19:7,20:7,21:8,22:8,23:8,24:9,
                                25:9,26:9,27:10,28:10,29:10,30:11,31:11,32:11,33:12,34:12,35:12,36:13,
                                 37:13,38:13,39:14,40:14,41:14,42:15,43:15,44:15,45:16,46:16,47:16,48:17,
                                49:17,50:17,51:18,52:18,53:18,54:19,55:19,56:19,57:20,58:20,59:20,60:21,
                                61:21,62:21,63:22,64:22,65:22,66:23,67:23,68:23,69:24,70:24,71:24,72:25,
                                73:25,74:25,75:26,76:26,77:26,78:27,79:27,80:27,81:28,82:28,83:28,84:29,
                                 85:29,86:29,87:30,88:30,89:30,90:31,91:31,92:31,93:32,94:32,95:32,96:33,
                                 97:33,98:33,99:34,100:34,101:34,102:35,103:35,104:35,105:36,106:36,107:36,108:37,
                                109:37,110:37,111:38,112:38,113:38,114:39,115:39,116:39,117:40,118:40,119:40,120:41,
                                121:41,122:41,123:42,124:42,125:42,126:43,127:43,128:43,129:44,130:44,131:44,132:45,
                                 133:45,134:45,135:46,136:46,137:46,138:47,139:47,140:47,141:48,142:48,143:48,144:49,
                                 145:49,146:49,147:50,148:50,149:50,150:51,151:51,152:51,153:52,154:52,155:52,156:53,
                                 157:53,158:53,159:54,160:54,161:54,162:55,163:55,164:55,165:56,166:56,167:56,168:57,
                                169:57,170:57,171:58,172:58,173:58,174:59,175:59,176:59,177:60,178:60,179:60,180:61,
                                181:61,182:61,183:62,184:62,185:62,186:63,187:63,188:63,189:64,190:64,191:64,192:65,
                                193:65,194:65,195:66,196:66,197:66,198:67,199:67,200:67,201:68,202:68,203:68,204:69,
                                205:69,206:69,207:70,208:70,209:70,210:71,211:71,212:71,213:72,214:72,215:72,216:73,
                                217:73,218:73,219:74}

df['season_ordinal'] = df.year_month_num.map(year_month_num_to_season_num)
```

Comment: here's a clue: `month_num//3` will give you a number 0-3 (assuming month_num ranges from 0 to 11).  It's integer division, where you ignore the remainder.

Comment: also if I understand this correctly `year_month_num%12` should give you back the `month_num`.  so `(year_month_num%12)//3` should give you a season index.  again assuming all these numberings start from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping dictionary can be given exactly by a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
year_month_num_to_season_num = {i:(i+3)//3 for i in range(1,220)}
```

This uses integer division. A certain amount of shifting was required in the value part so that the first two values are `1`.